# DOS system path

Tags: dos, cmd

Is there a way to programmatically, through a batch file (or powershell script), put all folders in `c:\Program Files` into the system variable `PATH`? I'm dependent on the command line and really want to just start a program from the command line.

Yes, I'm jealous of Linux shells.

Answer (score 6):

Passing in "C:\Program Files" as a parameter into this batch file:

```
@echo off

FOR /D %%G IN (%1\*) DO PATH "%%G";%path%
```

Answer (score 5):

Doing this is very likely to break your computer, in the sense of invoking DLL Hell.  As you invoke each executable, the OS will look through each directory in `PATH` to find each DLL or even EXE referenced by that executable.  It becomes highly likely that the OS will find the wrong ones as you add more directories to the `PATH`.

So, a best practice is to avoid increasing the `PATH`, and even to decrease it.  Rather than implicit dependencies, make them explicit.

Instead, I recommend this approach:

1. Create a `bin` directory within your user home directory
2. Add that `bin` directory to your user `PATH` variable
3. Create a Windows CMD script in the `bin` directory for each application that you want to invoke from the command line (same name as the executable that you would type)
4. In each script, invoke `SetLocal`, add the application's install directory (under `%ProgramFiles%`) to the `PATH`, then invoke the executable with the arguments from the command line
5. Remove the relevant directory from the `PATH`, so that this script becomes the only way to invoke the executable

Comment: This has the added benefit of not creating the huge security hole that the original question's goal would create. Just create C:\Program Files\AAAVeryBadDirectory\ with some malware in it as cmd.exe/devenv.exe/etc, and you're hosed when you run any of them.